# Greenhorn seeking oscilloscope advice

Tags: analog, oscilloscope, test-equipment

Let me make clear that I am at the crawling stage of "hobby" electronics.

I plan to build and tinker with analog stereo amplifiers, speaker crossovers, etc. (though who knows where anything leads)

An opportunity has presented itself, making it possible for me to get a decent* oscilloscope.

*My questions*:

**1**. What bandwidth do I need for my intended use?
**2**. Two or four channels?

Lastly, does the answer change if I get into digital audio?

Comment: For analog audio, most basic oscilloscopes are overkill, but if you progress to digital, a 100 MHz bandwidth would let you capture a sample of a digital audio stream. I doubt if you need 4 channels. Spend any leftover money on a signal generator with square and sine-wave outputs.

Comment: Audio don't require a lot of bandwidth. I'd get a basic 2 channel scope and instead spend the money ensuring you buy from a well-known vendor. Regretfully, I've spent my entire professional career using cheap ones and I use them a lot... next time I'll buy a high quality brand.

Comment: @Mark Leavitt Thank you for your response -- much appreciated

Comment: @Lundin - appreciated your response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For audio amps, high bandwidth is not strictly necessary, but it's nice to have at least 50MHz to spot local HF oscillations if they occur. Same if you use highspeed opamps in your designs. Two channels is OK. A digital scope isn't strictly necessary, but if you want to test non-repetitive stuff like short circuit protection, it helps a lot.

For amplifier stability characterization, ideally you'd need a network analyzer but that's expensive and complicated. However you can check if the amp is behaving well by using square waves and looking at tell tale signs of instability like ringing or overshoot. For this you need a scope with low phase shift and good waveform fidelity at a few MHZ, which a 20MHz scope may not provide. Anyway 50-100MHz is pretty much the standard.

Digital audio will involve I2S, probably I2C, maybe a microcontroller and other stuff. For this, a decent digital scope is a huge plus. When it misbehaves it's a lot more comfy to record a waveform and zoom in to look for what went wrong, or use the more elaborate triggering modes. You also need bandwidth, maybe 50-100MHz, to check for signal and power integrity problems: if your signal has ringing or overshoot, a slow 20MHz scope may smooth it out so you don't see anything. 4 channels is luxurious, you can display all four I2S lines (MCLK, BCLK, WS, DATA) on the same screen... however if your budget is limited, IMO it's better to get a 2 channel scope with higher bandwidth, lower noise and more features. This involves more juggling between channels when looking at I2S.

Next you need a signal generator with square, sine and triangle. This doesn't need to be expensive or high performance, but be wary of the super cheap aliexpress ones which often output lots of HF spikes along with the intended signal.

The usual digital scope with 8-bit DAC and lots of noise is rather useless to measure distortion at audio frequencies.

Then you need a soundcard ; stereo will do, but it is better if it does at least 96kHz sample rate. You can use the soundcard to plot the frequency response of amplifiers, crossover filters, loudspeakers (with a microphone) ; measure and plot impedance, distortion, output impedance and PSRR of voltage regulators, etc. Basically a soundcard is a low frequency signal generator, network analyzer, high-resolution scope, distortion analyzer, all in one.

It's also possible to measure lots of other things with a soundcard if you add simple DIY interfaces and a bit of code, for example by adding a phase detector, drift between two clocks can be measured. I used that to optimize a SPDIF receiver: phase detector measures phase between SPDIF generator clock and SPDIF receiver generated clock, which gives the amount of jitter added in the process. At some point I just input LRCK directly into the soundcard and it also worked. You can also add instrumentation amps or current sense amps, etc.

The motherboard's integrated soundcard is enough for most uses. An upgrade is a USB soundcard with balanced inputs, which gets rid of ground loop issues and also has less chances of blowing your motherboard if something goes wrong.

And... don't forget the power supply. I got a pair of Korad KD3005P (30V 5A). To test an audio amp, the current limit feature really helps to avoid smoke. 5A output current is much better than 3A in this case too. This one can be controlled via USB, so it can also be used to step voltage and current.

Comment: many thanks for a detailed answer -- any chance you can provide some ballpark specs to guide me toward a signal generator (or even a specific model or two)?

Comment: Well if you need a low distortion signal generator for sinewaves, a PC soundcard is ideal, and you already have a PC. However, clean square or triangle waves are useful and can't be generated by a soundcard because signals with sharp edges (square) or corners (triangle) require much more bandwidth to look clean. If you don't want to spend too much I'd say get a used signal generator, or a $5 kit from aliexpress. You can always get something more elaborate later.

Comment: I have [this one](http://aliexpress.com/item/4001224498670.html) from aliexpress, it works well but the output contains a bit of high frequency noise. If you're testing an amplifier for stability, it's annoying because you never know if the artifacts come from the generator or the amp under test...

Comment: thanks for taking the time to answer my novice questions

Answer (score 2):

It depends what you want to measure and why. Common audio sampling rates go up to 192 kHz, and audio op-amps have gain band-width to around 10 MHz. So a basic 10 or 20 MHz scope would work just fine, and you rarely need to compare more than two audio channels.

For digital signals it is much more complex. To see digital signals properly, it is the spees of signal edges that matter, not frequency. For audio with 192 kHz sampling rate, the bit clock could be 12.288 MHz and master clock could be 49.152 MHz. To see 50 MHz clock even adequately to know it's there, a scope with 100-200 MHz bandwidth may suffice. Digital audio buses have usually data, clock and latch signals of some sort, so two channels rarely suffice for anything but basic checking. But if you just use the scope to check that digital signals look good, a cheap logic analyzer can then be used to look at digital signals.